Restart Pods when config map values are updated. I am using Azure App Configuration Provider
We are currently using Azure App Configuration Service along with the Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider to fetch app configs/create config maps/mount volume with a file containing configs.
We use the refreshinterval and monitoring of a sentinel value to update the configs in the config map and configfile.  Some of our legacy apps require the container to be restarted in order for it to get the updated configs from the configfile.  Does the Azure App Configuration Provider have a feature for this?
If not, what would be the best way to approach this?
We are currently looking at this:
https://github.com/stakater/Reloader
However, for this we would need to find a way to add the annotation to the config map that is created by the App Configuration Provider.  Is there a way to do this with the config provider?
If not, how would we approach doing this?  We are trying to find a way to do this in Kubernetes rather than creating custom pipelines that restart pods when our config repos are updated.

There are 2 ways to perform a rolling upgrade on relevant DeploymentConfig or Deployment by using Reloader.

Annotate your Deployment. In this way annotations in configmap are not needed.


Add annotationreloader.stakater.com/auto to main metadata of your Deployment. And it will perform rolling upgrade on related pods when configmap generated by k8s provider updated.

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:


To perform rolling upgrade when change happens only on specific configmaps use below annotation. For a Deployment have a ConfigMap called configmap-generated-by-k8s-provider. Then add this annotation to main metadata of your Deployment.

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload: "configmap-generated-by-k8s-provider"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:


If you want to restrict this discovery to only ConfigMap or Secret objects that are tagged with a special annotation. To take advantage of that, you need to annotate both of your deployments and configmap like this:

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/search: "true"
spec:
  template:

Update the AzureAppConfigurationProvider resource of your Azure App Configuration Kubernetes Provider. And add annotations in metadata section, which looks like this:
apiVersion: azconfig.io/v1
kind: AzureAppConfigurationProvider
metadata:
  name: appconfigurationprovider-sample
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/match: "true"
spec:
  endpoint: <your-app-configuration-store-endpoint>
  target:
    configMapName: configmap-created-by-appconfig-provider

and Reloader will trigger the rolling upgrade upon modification of any ConfigMap annotated.
